# GHIDRA: Create an array of strings that are padded

Tags: ghidra

I'm working on decompiling a DOS .exe that was written in Pascal or Delphi. When looking at the decompiled code, there appears to be many strings that are are padded with `00`. Example:

```
06 53 54 52 49 4E 47 00 00 00 STRING
07 41 4E 4F 54 48 45 52 00 00 ANOTHER
08 4C 41 53 54 7F 4F 4E 45 00 LAST ONE
```

The leading number is the length of string, using Pascal conventions. If I were to run the .exe, these strings appear in a list. Because of this, I assume that the organization of the strings is supposed to be a list of some sort.

My questions are these:

1. Is there a way in Ghidra to puts these string into an Array, with one string per element? When I hit `[` it tries to build the array only off the length of the string and the characters of the first string and ignores the `00`.
2. Why was the code compiled this way. It would appear to increase the size of the file with addition padding byte(s), and I see these type of lists all over the decompiled file.

Comment: I am running into this same problem with an Arm cortex-M binary. The only solution I have found is manually editing the raw hex to place the terminated strings sequentially, then placing the removed padding bytes after the last string to keep everything aligned. Very hacky, I know.... but it works so far.

Answer (score 2):

While it'd be nice to define a struct using Ghidra's [flexible arrays](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24883/is-it-possible-to-define-an-array-of-variable-size-in-ghidra-size-in-the-struct), they are limited in functionality to the point where I haven't found them particularly useful.

In your case though, the padding bytes may actually make your life easier. If the strings are all 9 bytes like your example, you could do this:

```c
struct pstring {
  byte len;
  char[9] str;
}
```

And then make an array of `pstring` instances.